# how to check user credentials in mongodb application

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I created user model using devise with mysql database. and i want to check the user credentials from mongodb application. can anyone help me how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create extra for using mongoid.

Just skip active record while devise set up

```
—skip-active-record
```

Check this link for detail: http://suvankar.svbtle.com/devise-and-mongoid-in-rails-4

**Edit:**

If you want to use another database, you can add any number of database.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db1_dev
  username: root
  password: xyz
  host: localhost

development_sec:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db2_dev
  username: root
  password: xyz
  host: localhost
```

Here is an example how you connect seperate database for seperate model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sec"
end
```

When you adding the new migration for the second database, need to add following code to it.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def connection
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_sec").connection
  end

  def change
    # your code goes here.
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not asking to create application in mongodb. my question is:
I will put login page from mongodb application and i want to authenticate the user from another mysql database.